# AD User Properties returning property name not value

Tags: powershell

I am trying to loop through AD users to send them to a SOAP API.

For some reason, I get what looks like a distinguished name in the XML string instead of the property value.

```
# get list of users
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties mail, telephoneNumber, title, manager, company, l

ForEach($user in $users)
{
    # properties return expected values back to console
    $user.GivenName
    $user.Surname
    $user.title

# build XML payload
$body = @"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:saas="SaaS.Services">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <saas:InsertObject>
         <saas:commandData>
            <saas:ObjectType>Employee#</saas:ObjectType>
            <saas:Fields>
               <saas:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
                  <saas:Name>FirstName</saas:Name>
                  <saas:Value>$user.GivenName</saas:Value>
               </saas:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
               <saas:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
                  <saas:Name>LastName</saas:Name>
                  <saas:Value>$user.Surname</saas:Value>
               </saas:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
               <saas:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
                  <saas:Name>Title</saas:Name>
                  <saas:Value>$user.title</saas:Value>
               </saas:ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>
            </saas:Fields>
         </saas:commandData>
      </saas:InsertObject>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@    
}
```

I would expect to see Lara, Croft and Explorer for example in the XML string, and but I am actually getting:

```
CN=Lara Croft,CN=Users,DC=TESTLAB,DC=local.GivenName
CN=Lara Croft,CN=Users,DC=TESTLAB,DC=local.Surname
CN=Lara Croft,CN=Users,DC=TESTLAB,DC=local.title
```

Comment: Try to enclose `$User` in parenthesis ... like so: `$($User).GivenName`

Comment: I ended up putting parenthesis around the whole property like $($user.GivenName).  $(user).GivenName still gave me the property name.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to enclose the properties in $() parenthesis.  I could have assigned them to variables which worked OK, but was puzzled as to why I could not use them directly.